# Getting count of unsaved records in Indexeddb

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have some records saved in an Indexeddb, One of the fields in my db is "modifieddate". I want to get a count of all the records where modified date is not null.
I can count all records in my database like this:

```
 var request = store.count();
```

I have tried something like this:

```
  var myIndex = store.index('modifiedDate');
                    var cts = myIndex.count();
```

But that doesnt work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a count of the index should work. Make sure that you do not set the modifiedDate for objects that were never modified. If the modifiedDate property is undefined, null, or does not exist in the object's set of properties, then the index will not include the object, leading to only objects with a defined modifiedDate property being included in the modifiedDate index, which leads to count returning the property number.

The second problem is how you are using the count function. IDBObjectStore.count and IDBIndex.count return an IDBRequest object, not a number. You have to get the count asynchronously. This can be done easily using a callback function.

```
var countRequest = myIndex.count();
countRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var theActualCountNumber = event.target.result;

  // Alternatives to above statement, use whatever you like
  // var theActualCountNumber = countRequest.result;
  // var theActualCountNumber = this.result;

  console.log('Number of objects with a modifiedDate property: ',
    theActualCountNumber);
};
```

You cannot return 'theActualCountNumber' variable value from the callback function. It is only defined and accessible within the function. So, whatever code that wants to use the count value after you have obtained it must be located *within* the function itself. A simple trick to make the code cleaner and easier to use is the following:

```
function countModified(db, callback) {
  var tx = db.transaction('mystore');
  var store = tx.objectStore('mystore');
  var index = store.index('modifiedDate');
  var request = index.count();
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var count = event.target.result;
    callback(count);
  };
}

// An example of how to call it
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('mydb', myversion);
openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  countModified(db, onGetCountModified);
};

function onGetCountModified(count) {
  console.log('There are %s modified objects', count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the example was helpful as well. I hope this helps other's in a similar situation as well